# Are "configure" and "config.status" processes or input files?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

In the flowchart of autoconf and automake from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake ,
are "configure" and "config.status" processes or input files? 
Their representations are confusing to me, according to the legend in the bottom right corner.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `configure` and `config.status` are both executable files.

Comment: The flowchart shows a UML-like high-level description of autoconf and automake processes. In the flowchart, are `configure` and `config.status` processes or input files to some other processes?

Comment: If you want so, `configure` and `config.status` can be stated as processes. But basically they are files that get executed whenever the user configures the project. They are not like `aclocal` or `autoheader` that gets executed automatically by the configure system.

Comment: thanks. what is the input to `autoscan` process? Is the input to `autoscan` the source code to be built?

Comment: Well basically it scans the source directory and creates a configure.scan file.

Comment: do you mean the input is the source code directory? Is the output  `configure.scan` as you said or `configure.ac` as in the flowchart?

Comment: `autoscan` is just a helper tool to give you the first approximation of `configure.ac`.

Comment: Yes the input is the source directory and the output is `configure.scan` the best way to test what happens in each step is to try it out :)

Comment: Thanks. What process outputs `configure.ac`? @ck

Comment: @Tim `autoscan` outputs `configure.scan` which you modify to create `configure.ac`. The `configure.ac` file is a file that you then do not "re-generate" but rather modify manually.

Answer (score 2):

This diagram depicts files as a rectangle shape, and processes as elliptical shapes.

As `configure` and `config.status` are files which are generated, they have some straight lines from a rectangle around them.

And as `configure` and `config.status` are also programs which are run, they are also process names and thus contain some elliptical (here: circular) shape around it at the same time.